# Trying to perform a text change in my textview at a reoccurring time on daily basis in my android project

Tags: android, kotlin, time, calendar, date-format

> let say i will like to automatically change my textview text at 02:00pm everyday how do I implement this functionality.

```
val df = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.JAPAN).parse("2:00pm")
        val systemDat = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.JAPAN).after(df)
        if (systemDat) {
            binding.includeTokyoSession.text_one.text = "successful"
        } else {
            binding.includeTokyoSession.text_one.text = "failure"
        }
```

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `DateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Thanks so much Ole, I will try that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to change the text of your `TextView` after a particular time, but it seems that you're not aware of the date when comparing and you have a couple of mistakes in your code.

First, this line of code:

```
DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.JAPAN).parse("2:00pm")
```

will return a `Date` instance with this date and time in your local timezone `01-01-1970 02:00:00`. However, you need to get a `Date` instance with today's date and the time `14:00:00`.

Second, this line of code:

```
Calendar.getInstance(Locale.JAPAN).after(df)
```

this is a wrong usage of the `Calendar::after()` function, and that's because you can only pass a `Calendar` object to the function in order to get the right comparison result, otherwise it will always return false.

**In your case you're passing a `Date` object.**

Following is the implementation of the `Calendar::after()` function.

```
public boolean after(Object when) {
    return when instanceof Calendar
        && compareTo((Calendar)when) > 0;
}
```

If you want to proper compare the current time today with `14:00` (**comparing only the time today**), here is a modification to your code:

```
val calendarToCompare = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.JAPAN).apply {
    set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14)
    set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
    set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
    set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
}

val systemDat = Calendar.getInstance().after(calendarToCompare)

if (systemDat) {
    textview.text = "successful"
} else {
    textview.text = "failure"
}
```

If you want to perform a lifecycle-aware view update (ex. to set the text of your textview), you can check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mhdwajeeh95/07efb5f9f16761e6bf0d0306a5983c80).

Comment: mhdwajeeh.95 thanks for the answer, you are right your code ran with no exception unlike mine. What i am trying to achieve is to make my textview text change automatically at a daily time set and change back to normal after an elapse time of 9 hours on weekdays (monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday).  You seems to have a solid understanding of Date/Time and Calender API, do you think this could be solve by the  API or should i use AlarmManager API as Alarm app have similar functionality ?

Comment: Well, as your textview will only be visible to the user while the container of your view (activity/fragment) is focused and visible. So you need perform the code that update that text (in a repetitive manner with certain interval, eg. Every minute) only when your view container is visible to screen (eg. On activity resume) and stop to perform this code after that view container loses focus (eg. On activity pause).